# Unit test cases for a method which checks the device type

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am very new to unit testing. I have the following method for which I need to writes a test Method. Please help me with this.

Following is my method:

```
    private bool IsMobile()
    {
        var userAgent = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString() ?? "";
        return new Regex(@"Android|BlackBerry|iPhone|iPad|iPod|IEMobile", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline).IsMatch(userAgent);
    }


    public DeviceTypesEnum CheckDevice()
    {
        string userAgent = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString() ?? "";
        var tabletDevices = new Regex(@"ipad|android|android 3.0|xoom|sch-i800|playbook|tablet|kindle|nexus",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

        //Tablet Pc
        if (userAgent.ToLower().Contains("tablet pc"))
        {
            return DeviceTypesEnum.TabletPc;
        }

        var isMobile = IsMobile();
        // is desktop/ tablet block
        if (!isMobile)
        {
            return tabletDevices.IsMatch(userAgent) ? DeviceTypesEnum.Tablet : DeviceTypesEnum.Desktop;
        }

        // is mobile section block 
        var isPad = new Regex(@"ipad", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline).IsMatch(userAgent) ||
                    !(userAgent.ToLower().Contains("android") && userAgent.ToLower().Contains("mobile"));
        return isPad ? DeviceTypesEnum.Tablet : DeviceTypesEnum.Mobile;
    }
```

I have tried this which is failing though:

```
public class DetetctDeviceTest
{
    protected IDetectDevice Target;

    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void Initialize()
    {

        Target = AutoMocker.CreateInstance<DetectDevice>();            
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void CheckDeviceTest()
    {
        var obj = Target.CheckDevice();

        Assert.IsNotNull(obj);           

    }
}
```

Comment: What does "is failing" mean? Do you get any excepion? Did you debug your code and looked where it failed what you expect it to do?

Comment: Anyway: why do you mock your system under test at all? Having said this I assume your implementation for `CheckDevice` is never executed, but instead a mocked one, depending on your mocking-framework and on what `DetectDevice` actually is.

Comment: Message: Test method Dell.SupportOnline.Incidents.Web.Test.TestData.DetetctDeviceTest.CheckDeviceTest threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test CheckDevice method, you need to provide it with a mock of _httpContextAccessor. Then you will be able to run this test with different user-agent strings.

Comment: it helped me  :)